# Trying to add onclick function on <li> tag but click handle function is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get the value from my `<li>` tag in render but getting the undefined end result. I changed the code according to the suggested answers and now I got the result null.

```
handleClick= (e) => {
 console.log(e.target.getAttribute('device'));
}
render() {
      
 let { deviceData } = this.state;  
  return (

    <React.Fragment>
    
    {deviceData.map((result,i) => (
      <li key={i} className="nav-item" onClick= {this.handleClick} device= {result.device_title}>
        <a href="#"  className="nav-link"  >
           <i className="nav-icon fas fa-archway" />
             <p>
      
                {result.device_title}
            </p>
         </a>
      </li>
    ))}
    </React.Fragment>
  
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `li` tag is not receiving the click event. You can verify this by logging `e.target` before you log the `e.target.name`.

In addition to that, `li` tag does not accept `name` attribute, instead you should use `data-name` then access this value through `e.target.dataset.name`.

*Read more about [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)*

---

**Possible Solution**

Use the `data-name` attribute, disable the pointer events on the anchor (`a`) tag, and set your `li` to have `cursor: "pointer"`.

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    deviceData: [
      {
        device_title: "Device 1"
      },
      {
        device_title: "Device 2"
      }
    ]
  };

  handleClick(e) {
    console.log(e.target.dataset.name);
  }

  render() {
    let { deviceData } = this.state;
    return (
      <ul>
        {deviceData.map((result, i) => (
          <li
            key={i}
            onClick={this.handleClick}
            data-name={result.device_title}
            style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
          >
            <a href="#" className="nav-link" style={{ pointerEvents: "none" }}>
              <i className="nav-icon fas fa-archway" />
              <p>{result.device_title}</p>
            </a>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit festive-babbage-bjk0n]

Comment: Thank you very much everyone. you solved my problem. you guys are coool. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the property `handleClick` on `this`. However it is not bound to the scope of the constructor. You can either define it with an arrow function which will then be on the scope of the constructor so that it can be callable.

```js
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);


  this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}
```

You could also directly define it as an arrow function and call the method since arrow functions don't have their own this or arguments binding. Check the [Are 'Arrow Functions' and 'Functions' equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-exchangeable) question asked here for further information.

```
handleClick = () => {
 console.log('foo');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, **name** is not a property for the li tag, since it's not meant to be used with it.
It is an attribute, and you can access it in the following way:  `e.target.getAttribute('name')`

However, please read about which tags this should be used on at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes) or [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_name.asp).
I will really suggest naming the attribute something else though. :)

Comment: thanks for replying. i changed the attribute name and used e.target.getAttribute(). its result changed from undefined to null.

Answer (score 0):

The `target` is the element which was clicked on, not the element to which the event handler is bound. Probably the *paragraph* is the element receiving the click, not the `li` element.

Use [`currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) to get the element to which the event was bound.